# Foundation 6.5 Drilldown dynamic Back Text breaks data-auto-height

Tags: jquery, zurb-foundation

I'm using this little hack, to set the parent Item Text for the "back" Button dynamically at Drilldown Submenus.

Somehow the "back.text(parent.text())" breaks the auto height calculation. 
And the active Submenu is overlapping the parent Menu.

When i remove this Line, everything works as expected.

But why?

```js
$('[data-drilldown]').on('open.zf.drilldown', function(event) {
    var target = $(event.currentTarget).find('[aria-expanded="true"]'),
        parent = target.find('.menulink.level0'),
        back = target.find('.js-drilldown-back a');

    back.text(parent.text());
});
```

```html
<ul class="vertical menu large-horizontal" data-responsive-menu="drilldown large-dropdown" data-auto-height="true" data-animate-height="true">
    <li class=" menuitem level0">
        <a href="#" class="menulink level0" id="proda">Produkte</a>
        <ul class="menu vertical">
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">PräziPlan Präzisionsflachstahl</a>
                 </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">EcoPlan Präzisionsflachstahl kurz</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">PräziPlan Sonderabmessung</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">EroBlock Erodierklötze / -Ronden</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">EroBlock Sonderabmessung</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">P-Platten Sonderabmessung</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">VarioPlan gefräster Flachstahl</a>
                <ul class="menu vertical">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/calculator-material-configs/materials" class="menulink">Materialkosten</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/smallpart-additions/materials" class="menulink">Kleinteilzuschläge</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/calculator-article-configs/fraesen" class="menulink">Fräsen</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/calculator-article-configs?admin_group=varioplan" class="menulink">Sonstige Parameter</a>
                         </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">VarioRond Rundmaterial</a>
                <ul class="menu vertical">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/calculator-article-configs?admin_group=variorond_material_margin" class="menulink">Materialkosten</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/calculator-article-configs?admin_group=variorond" class="menulink">Sonstige Parameter</a> 
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/admin/calculator-material-configs/materials?productId=4" class="menulink">Werkstoffe-Durchmesser</a> 
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">Blankstahl</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">Rohmaterial Flach</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">Stahllexikon</a> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/admin/products/view?admin=1" class="menulink">Permanent-Lasthebemagnet</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing Text Manipulations outside the Event Handler work now as it should.

```js
$('.js-drilldown-back').each(function (i, v) {
    var back = $(v)
        .parent()
        .closest('.is-drilldown-submenu-parent')
        .find('> .menulink')
        .text();

    $(v)
        .find('a')
        .text(back);
});
```